# Multiple draggable with different color depending on which droppable it's in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have several divs. Some with class eucountry and some with class country. I want the divs with eucountry as class to turn green when it's in the droppable with #EU and red when it's in #not. I want the divs with class country to do the opposite.

Here is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".eucountry").draggable();


    $("#EU").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {

            $(ui.draggable).css("background-color", "green");
        }
    });

    $("#not").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {

            $(ui.draggable).css("background-color", "red");
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried to use an if statement that :

```
if($("div").hasClass("eucountry){
    $(ui.draggable).css("background-color", "red"); 
}
```

but it's not working.Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Is this about brexit? ;)

Comment: well kind of :P We find inspiration in everything

Comment: You probably have a lot of unnecessary code. do check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close, you have just to use the if statement inside `drop` callback, example :

```
$("#EU").droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) {
       if( $(ui.draggable).hasClass("eucountry") ){
           $(ui.draggable).css("background-color", "green"); 
       } 

       if( $(ui.draggable).hasClass("country") ){
           $(ui.draggable).css("background-color", "red"); 
       } 
   }
});

$("#not").droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) {
       if( $(ui.draggable).hasClass("eucountry") ){
           $(ui.draggable).css("background-color", "red"); 
       } 

       if( $(ui.draggable).hasClass("country") ){
           $(ui.draggable).css("background-color", "green"); 
       } 
   }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're missing the actual `if`s ;)

Comment: and even when I add the ifs it doesn't actually change the background color of the div :(

Comment: I changed this to ui.draggable. Then it worked :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make the drop actually append items into droppable, you can use CSS declarations:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px;
}
.droppable {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: grey;
}
.draggable {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
#EU .eucountry {
  background-color: green;
}
#EU .country {
  background-color: red;
}
#not .eucountry {
  background-color: red;
}
#not .country {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable country">Country</div>
<div class="draggable eucountry">EU country</div>
<br>
<div id="EU" class="droppable">EU</div>
<div id="not" class="droppable">NOT</div>
```